# How to make Background Worker DoWork() wait for further execution until processing is completed in ProgressChange() events?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, backgroundworker, background-process

I am quite new to background worker. so my logic may be wrong. Maybe i am not allow to do that. I am currently building my application on WPF.

I am using Background worker to scan for QR code (in the DoWork() function) and to display the scan results, I implemented in the ProgressChange() function (second portion of the code).

```
    void FaceDetectorWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (!FaceDetectorWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    string message;

                    message = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                    if (message != null)
                    {
                        reference = message;

                        int i = 0;
                        FaceDetectorWorker.ReportProgress(i, message);                           
                    }               
                }
                else
                    return;
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {                    

            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
```

In the ProgressChange() function, i displayed the scan results and at the same time I am checking if the scan results (Reference Number) exists in the database. This is what the RetrieveDatabase() function does and it return true or false.

```
  void FaceDetectorWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.UserState != null)
        {
            string text = e.UserState.ToString();
          
            tbxREFno.Text = text;
                         
            //Check if record exists in database
            bool result = RetrieveDatabase();

            if (result)
            {
                if (FaceDetectorWorker.IsBusy)
                    FaceDetectorWorker.CancelAsync();
                if (_serialPort.IsOpen)                    
                    _serialPort.Close();
                //go to the next page
            }
        }
    }
```

THE PROBLEM:

Technically, if the record exist in the database the serial port is close and the Background Worker is stop.
But, while retrieving the info in database in the progress changed function, the background worker WILL NOT WAIT and proceed. So, when the RetrieveDatabase() function call is completed, the "Serial Port" will be closed but the background worker is still running so I always hit an error here.
My Question --> Is my current implementation correct? if so, how can i make the background worker to wait until everything in the progress change has completed succesfully?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `BackgroundWorker` wrong.

The point is that `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` executes asynchronously. This is why the `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` handler continuous to execute while `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` is being handled.

The modern pattern to report progress to the UI is to use `Progress<T>` instead of the `BackgroundWorker`.

To fix your issue you should only report progress when there is some e.g. the record doesn't exist. If waiting is really necessary inside the `DoWork` handler, use the asynchronous version `await Task.Delay` (instead of the synchronous `Task.Sleep`):

```
async void FaceDetectorWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    while (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                string message = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                if (message != null)
                {
                    // Check if record exists in database
                    if (RetrieveDatabase())
                    {
                        if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
                            backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
                        if (_serialPort.IsOpen)                    
                            _serialPort.Close();

                        // Record exists => cancel
                        return;
                   }            
                
                    // Record doesn't exist => report progress
                    reference = message;
                    int i = 0;
                    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i, message);                           
                }               
            }
            else
                return;
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {                    

        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
    }
}

// Is only called when record doesn't exist
void FaceDetectorWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    if (e.UserState != null)
    {
        string text = e.UserState.ToString();
      
        tbxREFno.Text = text;
    }
}
```

The modern .NET Standard 1.0 version using [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=netcore-3.1):

```
public async Task ScanQrCodeAsync()
{
  IProgress<string> progressReporter = new Progress<string>(DisplayScanResult_OnProgressChanged);

  await Task.Run(async () => await FaceDetectorWorker_DoWorkAsync(progressReporter));
}

private void DisplayScanResult_OnProgressChanged(string message)
{
  // TODO::Display progress
}

async Task FaceDetectorWorker_DoWorkAsync(IProgress<string> progressReporter)
{
    while (_serialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        try
        {
            string message = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            if (message != null)
            {
                // Check if record exists in database
                if (RetrieveDatabase())
                {
                    if (_serialPort.IsOpen)                    
                        _serialPort.Close();

                    // Record exists => cancel
                    return;
                }            
                
                // Record doesn't exist => report progress
                progressReporter.Report(message);                           
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {               
        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your kind comment. let me try out this and get back to you!

Comment: Alright. If you want to use the `IProgress<T>` version, notice that `FaceDetectorWorker_DoWorkAsync` should return a `Task` instead of `void`. I have updated this. I overlooked it when copying the original method.